# Use dateTimePicker value to set scheduled task

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, scheduled-tasks

I have created a windows form in Visual Studio,

I want to be able to run a scheduled task using the users selected value from the dateTimePicker.

So once the user has selected the date and time they wish the .exe to run, I need this to be set as a scheduled task.

I have reaserched how to run windows scheduler programatically and found that there is options using `Taskscheduler` but I am using 3.5 and this assembly is not available?

Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) class is part of the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace. You have to reference it first by doing a `using System.Threading.Tasks;` in your class.

You can then refer to [these sample codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx) on how to use the `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: it picks up using.System.Threading; but I cant add Tasks to the end of it? The error asks if I am missing an assembly?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to TaskScheduler by whatever means, you can create a windows service by yourself to do this scheduling. You would dump the value picked by users to a file, registry or whatever, then read that value with your service and fire a timer that resets itself in the interval ValueReadFromFile - DateTime.Now.

Something like that, naively speaking.

---

Forgot to say: obviously, you would create and launch a process with that EXE once the timer elapses.